# Data.frame manipulation in R

Tags: r

I have got this information in R Studio

> a <- 1:10 b <- 30:39 c <- 50:59 d <- 45:54 e <- 34:43
>
> df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)

What I want to do is to rewrite it, but just in one column. I would thank you a lot

Comment: `stack(df)` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

As onyambu mentioned you can use stack(), or u can go for tidy verse solution using gather().
Hope this helps!

```
a <- 1:10 
b <- 30:39 
c <- 50:59 
d <- 45:54 
e <- 34:43

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
stack(df)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% gather()
```